# Specific dynamic numbering in excel

Tags: excel, numbers, row

I have a question,

is there are any way to make numbering format in excel ( 1; 1.1; 1.2.... )with formula?

I need to hide second row, numbering should be dynamic and still show

(1; 1.1; 1.2...) not (1; 1.2)...

and i need to lock first (1) number by specific row.

Because i have 3 to 3.45 then 4 to 4.20 ...

[image]

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8gD2IS9mD80WGtaaWlkaVpfWjA/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the simple formula to do this.

```
=1&"."&ROW(A1)
```

Drag the formula to down to get the desired numbering you want . you just need to change the start `1` to any number you want as starting point like `3` or `4` .

Comment: Sorry hold on as i am in office my Drive access has been blocked by administrator. Just give me a moment to get the file from diff source will let you know soon.

Comment: maybe you know how to do it?

Comment: maybe i can use =SUBTOTAL?

Comment: @SkirmanteValentaite you can use the formula `=1&"."&ROW(A1)`

Comment: i found way with this formula :) =AGGREGATE(4;5;$O$19:O20)+0.1

Answer (score 0):

i found the way!
i'm using =AGGREGATE function. 
its looking max value in array and skipping blanks. and i wrote +0.1 that then he find max value its adding 0.1

it looks like this:

=AGGREGATE(4;5;$O$19:O20)+0.1